# python fast fourier coefficients filtering and thresholding deciding

Tags: python, lambda, fft

I am trying to analyze a long period sequence of float numbers. I would like to conduct fast fourier transformation on the numbers and then remove low coefficient one. There are two questions:

1  how to set these noise coefficient efficients less than threshold to 0 in an efficient way.
e.g   Arr=[100, 2, 50, 4, 15, 7],  threshold = 5, return = [ 100, 0,50,0,15,7]. I suspect I should use lambda related trick, but I am still newbie to Python

2   Is there a thumb rule to decide the threshold, guys experienced with FFT or with signal processing please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A **numpy solution** to the threshold will be faster than list comprehensions or lambdas, and easier to write and read, and you'll probably be using numpy for the FFT anyway:

```
import numpy as np
Arr=np.array([100, 2, 50, 4, 15, 7])

Arr[Arr<8] = 0  
# array([100, 0, 50, 0, 15, 0])
```

There is also `scipy.stats.threshold`, but it just basically does what's above.

For the question about the threshold, it depends entirely on the nature of the signal and the noise, so there's no good rule of thumb.  For example, if you have a part of the sample that you know is just noise, then it's fairly obvious what to do; and if you don't and your signal is exactly like the noise, then you shouldn't threshold at all.  It depends on the details.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a lambda for your first question, rather you can use list comprehensions.

```
>>> print [n if n > 5 else 0 for n in [100, 2, 50, 4, 15, 7]]
```

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2104) on stats might provide some insight on determining a threshold.